# How do you define a subclass of UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

We were having issues with our app not rotating but that problem has been solved. We now need to force our views into protrait mode.

The best scenario would be to define a subclass of our UITabBarController and then override supportedInterfaceOrientations with a portrait mask.

I can't seem to figure out how to properly subclass our UITabBarController. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on project and choose to create a new objective-c Class and then write UITabBarController in subclass of text box. Done.

[image: Create New File]

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented custom tab bar controllers in a couple of projects.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTabBarController : UITabBarController<UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{

}

@end
```

You can make it like any other Objective-C class.
One very interesting way of using tab bar controller I found, was having a custom view over tab bar with buttons. You can customize your tab bar with any size or shape of tabs and you can write action on those custom tabs to change the tab for the tab barcontroller.